# Как лучше всего проверить, что окно существует?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, winapi

Допустим, я пишу функцию, которая по значению дескриптора должна вернуть логическое значение, существует ли окно с таким дескриптором. Я представляю огромное количество реализаций - от перебора всех окон через GetProcesses или EnumWindow и до вызова какой-нибудь функции, принимающей hwnd, и возвращающую результат. А может я все усложняю, а такая функция входит в user32. В общем, как будет лучше и быстрее?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть WinApi функция  [IsWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633528%28VS.85%29.aspx), но как пишут в [этом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344233/validate-hwnd-using-win32-api) ответе хендл может переназначаться => если вы пасете определенное окно и хотите проверить его существование, то окно может быть уже закрыто, но хендл с таким же номером был создан для другого окна.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Получается, что имеет смысл воспользоваться вот этой функцией, если у окна есть специфическое название [GetWindowText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) , она вернет `Caption` окна и можно удостоверится, что именно желаемое окно живо.

Через WinApi я думаю, что быстрее.

**Что лучше?**

Все зависит от того, как часто вы это собираетесь делать. Если не часто, то я бы не заморачивался и выполнял итерацию по процессам.

Comment: Спасибо, упустил из виду IsWindow!